# ¿Cual es mi error en esta consulta de MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Intento llamar los datos de las columnas "RFC_UsuaAG" y "Nombre_AdminGeneral" de dos tablas diferentes las cuales son "admingeneral" y "usuariosag" pero al momento de ejecutar mi sintaxis me muestra como si tuviera dos datos iguales (los cuales no tengo)

Esta es la consulta que ejecuto:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RFC_UsuaAG, Nombre_AdminGeneral FROM usuariosag INNER JOIN admingeneral
```

Así es como me lo muestra:
[image: Me aparece una advertencia pero no se a que se esta refiriendo y si esta relacionado a mi consulta]

Y estos son los datos que tengo en mis dos tablas "admingeneral" y "usuariosag":
[image: admingeneral]

[image: usuariosag]

Como ven no tengo datos repetidos y en la consulta que ejecuto me muestra otro "Miguel" y "yenis"

No sé si estoy mal o es un error en mi sintaxis, tal vez sea otra cosa no lo sé, cualquier ayuda se los agradecería mucho por favor :D

Comment: Saludos. Será que falta el `ON`?.

Comment: Buenas bro, exactamente donde podría el ON en la sintaxis?

Comment: Saludos. Luego del `INNER JOIN` justo después del nombre de la tabla  (yo al menos así lo hago) es usar la instrucción `ON` (ver https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) y esto en cualquier Base de Datos. Bueno al menos de momento es mi observación al respecto.

Comment: Hoo! va entiendo. Ya agregue el ON en mi sintaxis la cual quedaría así: SELECT DISTINCT RFC_UsuaAG, Nombre_AdminGeneral FROM usuariosag INNER JOIN admingeneral ON usuariosag.RFC_UsuaAG = admingeneral.Nombre_AdminGeneral.

Pero al momento de ejecutarlo no me aparece ningún dato, no se si escribí mal la consulta o es por otra cosa.

Comment: Estás uniendo por las columnas equivocadas

Comment: Yo también pensé eso... pero no entiendo o como explicas el por que se repiten los datos. Si me muestra los datos con la primera consulta (pero duplicados) por que con esta otra no me muestra nada xd @LuisCazares

Comment: segun veo tus tablas el ON lo tendrías que generar como  `SELECT DISTINCT RFC_UsuaAG, Nombre_AdminGeneral FROM usuariosag INNER JOIN admingeneral ON usuariosag.UsuariosAG_ID= admingeneral.UsuariosAG_ID`,  En el inner join tienes que poner las columnas por las que hara el cruce tu join.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias ya me funciono, pero aun no entiendo algo... después del `ON` pones `usuariosag.UsuariosAG_ID= admingeneral.UsuariosAG_ID` y no `usuariosag.UsuariosAG_ID= admingeneral.AdminGeneral_ID`. Por que se repite en los dos campos "UsuariosAG_ID"??? @EduardoJaramilloLicea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchas gracias por su ayuda @RobertoLeOr, @LuisCazares, @EduardoJaramilloLicea y @Jose la consulta ya me la ejecuta correctamente :D. Que tengan un excelente Miércoles y éxito en todo lo que hagan

[image: ¡Gracias!]

Comment: Hola! QUé bien que encontraste la solución aquí. Eso sí, acá abajo de tu pregunta sólo van los intentos de respuesta. Si la respuesta que dio Jose te sirvió, márcala como aceptada (el tick junto al numerito, a la izquierda). Si entre todos te ayudaron y tú das la respuesta final, marca tu propia respuesta como aceptada (para que otros sepan después qué hacer si tienen el mismo problema). También le puedes dar votos positivos a todos los que te ayudaron si sus comentarios fueron útiles :)

Answer (score 1):

Trata siempre que hagas un select de los campos que precises, indicar antes de qué tabla vienen, a veces es posible que si un campo existe en dos tablas el motor de bbdd te devuelva error porque no sabe cual debe de coger.

P.e. (no se de donde está cada campo):

```
SELECT DISTINCT usuariosag.RFC_UsuaAG, admingeneral.Nombre_AdminGeneral FROM usuariosag INNER JOIN admingeneral
```

Además te falta poner el "on" al final como te han dicho primero indicando el nombredelatabla.campo quelasrelaciona=nombredeotratabla.campoquelasrelaciona